# Import content from old WordPress website to new WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, plugins, import, export, wordpress-theming

I want to import and export the old content template to a new content template with minimal editing or easier mapping.
Currently the difficulty we face is

example, if we have a content in an accordion element in the old site and in the new website, i prefer a normal text block, i couldn't.
Is there a way to overcome this issue.
Thanks in advance for your help!

[image: old site image]

in new site i need to put this content in to different element structure

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. It depends on the theme. Which theme (new and old) are you using?